# delete blanks in R

Tags: r, string

I'm currently working with several datasets in R. 
One of these datasets has blanks in every row before every country name such as
"     Afghanistan". If I now want to merge this dataset with another dataset by country name R can't match the names because of the blanks. I now want to remove these blanks before every name but not between the names: e.g. the blank between "The" and "Bahamas" should stay there and only the blanks before the name should disappear in every row. 
How can I do that?

Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `trimws` from `base R` to remove the leading/lagging spaces in each string.  Suppose if the column name is "countryname", we apply the `trimws` on that column and assign back the output to the same column.

```
df1$countryname <- trimws(df1$countryname)
```

Comment: Neat! `substring` should also do it, e.g. `df1$countryname <- substring(df1$countryname,2)`.

Comment: @Gumeo It could be possible, but we don't know how many white spaces are present for each string.

Comment: True! OP mentions blanks in plural, so you're right!

Comment: Worked all fine
Thank you very much